# samsung galaxy s wifi 4.0 large screen for android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Short one: Am I correct in assuming, that the Samsung Galaxy S wifi 4.0 is a large screen in terms of android (2.3) layouts?

Thanx, Marcus

Comment: Does it matter? Are you writing a program just for this one device? Just create layouts that support multiple screen sizes.

Comment: nope, just beginning and trying to clear some of the docu up while I go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the table given at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing, that device should be a normal hdpi device as it is 4 inches, with a resolution of 480x800, giving it a density of 233.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is a large screen.
To test it, create different layouts (small, medium and large) with different content and run the app.